# Cannot see Browse image option in magento 1

Tags: product, product-images, magento-1.9.2.0

I am using magento 1.9.2.0
I cannot see Browse option to add images. What can be the issue. 
See https://prnt.sc/rapqp5
However, i can see the option in Magento 1.9.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

You install flash plugin in your browser and try again.

Comment: i did. Still same issue